# add search bar to filtring the data inside the entityType fields in symfony6

Tags: php, symfony6

i have an issue, i want to filtring the output data in this entityType
i found a solution but i should to change the value of searchterm inside the script,

```
$searchTerm = 'ri';

$builder->add('userInput', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => User::class,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($searchTerm) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->where('u.username LIKE :searchTerm')
                        ->setParameter('searchTerm', '%'.$searchTerm.'%')
                        ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'username',
                'required' => false,
            ])
```

i want to add bar search inside this entityType to filtring the data of u.username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, just implementation of Select2 in JS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).